# OpenCourseWare but for Example Questions?

Tags: online-resource, learning

Part of my job is creating learning materials (such as example questions) mostly for first year undergraduate students in engineering. I find it difficult to believe that there are not free online resources for example questions based on topics. It is crazy to think that every time an institute wants example questions they have to make them from scratch, instead of having an online place for people to post.

MIT OpenCourseWare has some assignment materials, however you cant search by topic (e.g., search for "eigenvalues"). Also, there aren't many assignments per topic (and some require you to have the book which defeats the purpose).

**Is there anything similar out there I could use to get examples from and even put my own examples out there for others to use?**

(Keep in mind it has to be official, I know there are some places where students can upload materials from their courses, but those are usually not done with permission.)

Comment: I have to write mine for my quizzes : takes time and effort... But those questions are tailored around the material I teach and the way I teach it...

Comment: Not engineering related, but the WeBWorK Open Problems Library is a collection of mathematics problems for use with the WeBWorK system for computer-based homework.

Comment: Dont you need to be faculty in an institute that uses WeBWorK in order to have a user to be able to access it? (im in Canada ON)

Comment: The WeBWorK server software is open source, so anyone should be able to build it and setup their own server.  I agree that you wouldn't really want to access the problems without using a server, but you could download the library of problems from github if you want.

Comment: The obvious disadvantage of a central repository of questions is that there will soon be a central repository of answers that the students use.